# Complex function that is differentiable but not continuous in the neighborhood

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm looking for a complex function $f(z)$ such that it's differentiable at $z = z_0$ but isn't continuous in any neighborhood of $z = z_0$. I don't think differentiability in one point implies continuity in some neighborhood but I couldn't find a counterexample for that.

This question occurred to me when I encountered with the following theorem:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(x)=z^{2}$ for  $z$ on the real axis and $f(z)=z^{3}$ everywhere else is such a  function.

Comment: Could you show how this function satisfies those conditions, please?

Comment: The derivative at $0$ is $0$ since $\frac {z^{k}-0} z \to 0$ as $ z\to 0$ for $k=2$ as well as $k=3$. Any open disk around $0$ contains points $z$ with $z^{2} \neq z^{3}$. At any such a point the function is not continuous. @S.H.W

Comment: Does this function satisfy in Cauchy–Riemann equations? And in general is continuity in some neighborhood necessary for these equations?

Comment: The partial derivatives don 't even exist in any open disk around the origin.

Comment: What about origin? In that point is it true that $u_x  = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$?

Comment: At the origin all the partial derivatives are $0$ so C-R equations are satisfied.

Comment: So the only condition for C-R equations is differentiability in that point, right?

Comment: @S.H.W Yes, that is right.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in the Erwin Kreyszig's book continuity in the some neighborhood of point is also assumed and I wondered why it's necessary.

Comment: @S.H.W K assumes continuity of _what_, in _what_ result? Complex differentiability at a point implies the CR equations at that point, but knowing the CR equations at a point does _not_ imply complex differentiability at that point.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Please see the edited question.

Comment: @S.H.W Well, that result in K is just silly, because the fact that it holds under much weaker hypotheses is completely trivial, using nothing but the definitions.